# How to define letter in custom layout (xkb)?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm using Arch Linux.
I'm trying to define, for example, letter '**a**' with **double grave** in xkb custom layout.
It's easy to define, for example, '**a**' with grave:

```
key <AC01> {[ a, A, agrave, Agrave ]};
```

This works.
I tried something like:

```
key <AC01> {[ a, A, adoublegrave, Adoublegrave ]};
```

It isn't working. Also I want to define a letter with '**inverted breve**'.
If someone will, at least, give me an example, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify characters by their Unicode code point, so e.g. `U0201` and `U0203` should be the small `a` characters with the desired double grave and inverted breve. Use any Unicode table or list to find the others.

For all available key names, see `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`. There's no name for combined character with double grave or inverted breve though.

Comment: It's strange, though, that double-grave and inverted-breve isn't implemented :( , Thank you, anyway. Your answer was helpful.